# resources for classical gauge theory

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

As a prospective grad student, I would like to get an entry level introduction to classical (i.e. non-quantum) gauge theory.  Please direct me to resources suitable for a novice.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by classical gauge theory? I claim to do mathematical gauge theory but don't know the difference between what's classical and what's not.

Comment: I meant only to exclude quantum gauge theory which to me implies the theory of the standard model of particle physics.  I was thinking as an example of classical electrodynamics (ala Maxwell), but not quantum electrodynamics (ala Feynman).  I'd be happy to have any remarks you'd care to make, so feel free to disregard the classical part.

Comment: This sounds to me like a question that would be more applicable on Physics.SE. Have you tried posting it there?

Comment: It didn't occur to me because I'm interested in grad math, but I'll try it if I don't get a response in Math SE.  In the intro to Lee's book on smooth manifolds he mentions (among others) that gauge theory is an area in mathematics to which the theory of smooth manifolds applies.  It seemed to me at the time I read this that it might be of interest to me for a research topic, but i have not been able to find much about this field.

Comment: OK - if it turns out my answer isn't the sort of thing you were looking for, I would post your question on physics.

Answer (score 6):

Before saying what I think are good introductions to mathematical gauge theory, I should say what I think gauge theory is. What gauge theory means to me is the application of certain PDEs, relevant in physics, to the topology and geometry of manifolds. I note here that one can be ignorant of the actual physics (as I am). Here is one example.

Given a Riemannian 4-manifold $(M,g)$, one can write down a certain PDE called the "ASD equation", whose input is a connection on a $G$-bundle over $M$. (Usually $G=SU(2), U(2), SO(3).$) This equation has a rather large group of symmetries: that is, there is an (infinite-dimensional) Lie group $\mathcal G$ with an action on the space of connections $\mathcal A$ such that, if $A$ is a solution to the ASD equation, so is $g(A)$; so we usually consider it as an equation on the quotient space $\mathcal A/\mathcal G$. (The appearance of the word gauge in all this is that $\mathcal G$ is called the group of gauge transformations, and we're interested in solutions modulo gauge equivalence.) If you're lucky, the space of solutions in this quotient is 0-dimensional, and you can take a (signed) count of the points. Essentially, this is an invariant of the underlying smooth manifold $M$ - it did not depend on the metric $g$! This allows us to tell apart manifolds that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic; for instance, there is a countable infinity of smooth manifolds $D_q$, pairwise non-diffeomorphic, but all homeomorphic to $\Bbb{CP}^2 \# 9\overline{\Bbb{CP}^2}.$ Invariants from gauge theory or its cousins are thusfar the only known way to tell apart smooth 4-manifolds that are homeomorphic.

In addition to the ASD equation, also useful are the [Seiberg-Witten equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiberg%E2%80%93Witten_invariant); equations that might turn out to be useful (but are still in the early stages) include the Vafa-Witten equations and the Haydys-Witten equations. There are associated theories in 3 dimensions called Floer theories that are active areas of research; in 2013 Manolescu disproved the [Triangulation](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cm/tc.pdf) conjecture with a Floer-type theory with just slightly more symmetry than the better-known Seiberg-Witten Floer homology. Donaldson has a program to apply these ideas to the study of Riemannian manifolds with $SU(3), \text{Spin}(7)$, and $G_2$ holonomy; this is also still early (no actual invariants have been defined yet, I don't think) but active.

If one wanted to learn some of mathematical gauge theory, I think the best place to start is with the Seiberg-Witten equations, which have abelian gauge group (which simplifies quite a lot of the technical difficulty). My favorite introduction is Salamon's extensive notes on [Seiberg-Witten theory](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/witsei.pdf); it's self-contained, well-written, and contains a lot of material that's harder to find in other introductions. The canonical (well, only) reference for the ASD equations in 4 dimensions is Donaldson and Kronheimer's book "The Geometry of 4-Manifolds". I would say this is significantly harder than the Salamon notes.

As a last point, note again that this is highly influenced by physics, but everything I've said here is pretty disjoint from having to know it - I know no physics except for the mechanics course I took in undergrad 6 years ago, and this hasn't been an impairment.

Comment: Conversely, physicists seem to not be impaired by their lack of regard for the *mathematical* formulation of gauge theory: Parallel yet independent growth! :)

Comment: @Danu: I would probably not call it independent; the origins come from Atiyah's interest in physics, and all those equations originally come from physics, and we learn new things from the physicists all the time. I like to think we also contribute in the other direction but know too little to say.

Comment: Mike:  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for your well-crafted response.

Comment: @Emile You might also see this [previous answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1517951/98602) I wrote.